# To get list of bottom most or deepest or last child for specified parent category

Tags: list

I want to list all the last deepest / bottom most childs of a specified parent category in a page.
the structure is

- Parent A

  - child 1

    - grand child 1
  - child 2

    - grand child 2

      - great grand child 1
  - child 3

    - grand child 3

...
   I need to list all the last childs of specified parent, say for above example i need list for ParentA and the results should be like this

- grand child 1
- great grand child 1
- grand child 3

is there any code to display in a page. I'm new to wp and PHP. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`wp_list_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) to achieve that:

```
<ul>
    <?php
        wp_list_categories( array(
            'child_of' => <PARENT_ID>, // show only children of PARENT_ID
            'childless' => true, // show only categories without children
            'hide_empty' => true, // should empty categories be hidden
        ) );
    ?> 
</ul>
```

You can find full list of available params here: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/#parameters

Comment: thanks for reply. but using this childless=> true it shows no category. for childless => false it shows all childs and grand childs . I use  shortcode of 'php snnipets' plugin to insert php in my post. will that be problem or where i have to insert the above code in wp site.